# vs2012 Do not merge option is not working

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am visual studio 2012. When i am trying to publish my asp.net webform website by using the "`Advanced Precompile Settings Dialog Box`" there is option "`Do not merge`".

After publishing merge all files in single assembly. I want separate assembly of each page.

"`Do not merge`" option is not working could you please help out me.